# For $f:\mathbb R^{<0}\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=2x^2-3$, find the values of a for which $f(a)=f^{-1}(a)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Okay, i've got the answer for this with some luck I guess, however i'm still left wondering  specifically what this part of the question means:
"find the values of a for which $f(a)=f^{-1}(a)$"

My understanding of this is, that the question is asking me to find a value of a where the output and input given by the function $f$ are equal?

Could someone do a better job of explaining this to me please, thank you.

Comment: And $f(f(a))= a.$

Comment: The inverse function of $f$ is not well defined, because $f$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: This question is a little bit silly, since $f^{-1}(a)$ is a set rather than a value (e.g. $f^{-1}(-1)=\{-1,1\})$. The best you can do is what everyone's suggesting.

Comment: Ah sorry, the domain is x<0 for all reals

Comment: @IanColey, the textbook says that the notation to use when denoting the inverse function

Comment: With your additional information, $f$ is now one-to-one so this inverse function is well defined, i.e. $f^{-1}(a)$ is a singleton set for each point in the image of $f$.

Comment: @Assad Now the function is one-to-one; so the hints given in the answers should take you on the right path.

Comment: @egreg, why should I do f(f(a))=a? I dont see how inputting the value f(a) back into f is equal to a. Explin to me what this means f(f(a))=a, because I think i may have misunderstood it..

Comment: @Assad $f(a)=f^{-1}(a)$ is equivalent, since $f$ is one-to-one, to $f(f(a))=f(f^{-1}(a)$, assuming $f(a)$ belongs to the domain of $f$. But $f(f^{-1}(a))=a$ by definition (assuming $a$ belongs to the set of values of $f$).

Comment: @egreg, Isnt $f(f(a))=a$, a really convoluted way of doing it? I did $f(a)=a$ and got the right answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for which $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ must lie on the line $y=x$, since by the sheer definition of inverse function this is an axis of symmetry. This means that if a function and its inverse intersect, the points of intersection must lie on that line. Hence, you have to solve for which values of $x$ we have $f(x)=x$. So $2x^2-3=x$ and this leads to $x=-1$ or $x=1\frac{1}{2}$. Since your domain is the negative reals, you are left with $x=-1$.

Comment: This is only a sufficient condition; also $x=-(1+\sqrt{21})/4$ is a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: I don't think so ...

Comment: @NickyHekster, your answer is the right one. I dont understand what the others are telling me to do, why does $f(f(a))=a$? Surely it's ${f^{ - 1}}(f(a)) = a$?

Comment: Assad if you deem my answer the right one please tick it as such. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: it is correct that if $f^{-1}(a)=f(a)$, then $f(f^{-1}(a))=f(f(a))$ and hence $id(a)=a=f^2(a)$ (where the 2 does not denote squaring, but abbreviates $f \circ f$). But this way of solving the problem introduces more "roots" in the fourth degree equation you worked out.

Comment: Thanks @NickyHekster you really clarified everything!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$f(a) = f^{-1}(a) \Longrightarrow f(f(a))=a.$$

Comment: Could you explain why this is?

Comment: @Assad By definition of inverse function.

Comment: I dont get it...

Comment: If I do f(f(a))=a, I get this:
$$\eqalign{
  & f(x) = 2{x^2} - 3  \cr 
  & f(a) = 2{a^2} - 3  \cr 
  & f(f(a)) = a:  \cr 
  & a = 2{(2{a^2} - 3)^2} - 3  \cr 
  & a = 2(4{a^4} - 12{a^2} + 9) - 3  \cr 
  & a = 8{a^4} - 24{a^2} + 15  \cr 
  & 8{a^4} - 24{a^2} - a + 15 = 0 \cr} $$
How on earth do I solve that?

Comment: @Assad You can apply rational root theorem to decrease the degree of the degree of the polynomial, otherwise this is quartic equation and can be "easily" solved using Ferrari's method.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for periodic points of period 2.

First find $f(f(a))$. Then set it equal to $a$ and solve for $a$.